# Update region to be around Annotations

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a `mapView` with some annotations and I'd like to center the map around the `annotations`. I have the following code:

```
- (void)updateRegion {
    self.needUpdateRegion = NO;
    CGRect boundingRect;
    BOOL started = NO;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations){
        CGRect annotationRect = CGRectMake(annotation.coordinate.longitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude, 0, 0);
        if (!started) {
            started = YES;
            boundingRect = annotationRect;
        } else {
            boundingRect = CGRectUnion(boundingRect, annotationRect);
        }
    } if (started) {
        boundingRect = CGRectInset(boundingRect, -0.2, -0.2);
        if ((boundingRect.size.width >20) && (boundingRect.size.height >20)) {
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            region.center.latitude = boundingRect.origin.x + boundingRect.size.width /2;
            region.center.longitude = boundingRect.origin.y + boundingRect.size.height / 2;
            region.span.latitudeDelta = boundingRect.size.width;
            region.span.longitudeDelta = boundingRect.size.height;
            [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

        }
    }
}
```

it gets executed in `viewDidAppear` to make the "sliding effect":

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.needUpdateRegion) [self updateRegion];
}
```

When I run the app it doesn't do anything and just shows the US.
The annotations are shown (in Europe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `updateRegion` gets called in the first place (make sure `needUpdateRegion` is initialized to `YES`), there are two main problems with the `updateRegion` method:

1. It only calls `setRegion` if the resulting bounding map rect's width and height are 20.  Since you are doing the calculations using latitude and longitude degrees, this means `setRegion` will only get called *if the resulting bounding map rect is more than 20 **degrees*** latitude/longitude wide/high.  It's not clear if this is what you intended.
2. The `region` properties are being set backwards.  In the calculation of the bounding map rect, the `x` values are set to the longitude and the `y` values are set to the latitude.  But when setting `region.center.latitude`, it is using `boundingRect.origin.x` instead of `boundingRect.origin.y`.  This applies to the other properties as well so the code there should be:

   ```
   region.center.longitude = boundingRect.origin.x + boundingRect.size.width /2;
   region.center.latitude = boundingRect.origin.y + boundingRect.size.height / 2;
   region.span.longitudeDelta = boundingRect.size.width;
   region.span.latitudeDelta = boundingRect.size.height;
   ```

Note that iOS 7 provides a new convenient method [`showAnnotations:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW83) to automatically show the annotations so you don't have to calculate the region yourself.

So in `updateRegion` you could do the following:

```
- (void)updateRegion {
    self.needUpdateRegion = NO;

    //if showAnnotations:animated: is available, use it...
    if ([mapView respondsToSelector:@selector(showAnnotations:animated:)])
    {
        [self.mapView showAnnotations:mapView.annotations animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    //calculate region manually...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `showAnnotations:animated:` works perfectly well. I could also fix my original code by exchanging the numbers to very little ones (since the annotations are very close to each other). Since I write the App especially for iOS 7, is it better to just drop the original code and only use `showAnnotations:animated:`?

Comment: If the app is only designed for iOS 7 or higher, then yes I would just use showAnnotations if that works for you.